# gfortran pointer procedure type issue

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to have a procedure that can accept different input types without using a generic procedure. Indeed, (in this case) I prefer to set manually the target of a procedure pointer to define the procedure to use rather than a generic procedure.

This is what I do with the following almost minimal example.

```
module mo
implicit none

type :: TypeB
    character(len=5) :: info='Hello'
    contains
    procedure,  pass(fd) :: say_hello 
end type TypeB

type :: TypeA
    character(len=4) :: txt='Hola'
    !type(TypeB) :: Tb
end type TypeA

type, extends(TypeA) :: TypeC
    character(len=4) :: tt='Hey!'
    type(TypeB) :: Tb
end type TypeC

type, extends(TypeA) :: TypeD
    character(len=3) :: tt='Ho!'
    character(len=3) :: ti='you'
    !type(TypeB) :: Tb
end type TypeD

type(TypeC) :: Tc
type(TypeD) :: Td
procedure(), pointer :: proc
class(TypeA), allocatable :: CA


contains

subroutine say_hello(fd)
    implicit none
    ! type(TypeB), intent(inout) :: fd
    class(TypeB), intent(inout) :: fd

    print *, fd%info

end subroutine say_hello

subroutine procC(fd, args)
    implicit none
    ! class(TypeC), intent(inout) :: fd
    type(TypeC), intent(inout) :: fd
    real :: args

    print*, args
    print*, fd%tt
    call fd%Tb%say_hello()
end subroutine procC

subroutine procD(fd, args)
    implicit none
    ! class(TypeD), intent(inout) :: fd
    type(TypeD), intent(inout) :: fd
    ! class(TypeA), intent(inout) :: fd
    real :: args

    print*, args
    print*, fd%tt
    print*, fd%ti
end subroutine procD

end module mo


program p
    use mo
    implicit none

    print* , 'START'
    print *, Tc%tb%info
    print *, Tc%txt
    call Tc%Tb%say_hello()
    call procC(Tc, 1.0)
    call procD(Td, 2.0)
    print*, 'OK'

    allocate(TypeD :: CA)
    proc =>procD
    call proc(CA, 3.0)
    deallocate(CA)

    allocate(TypeC :: CA)
    proc =>procC
    call proc(CA, 4.0)
    deallocate(CA)

    print*, 'END'

end program p
```

I get the expected results when I compile with ifort on Linux but when I compile with gfortran (MinGW 6.2.0) on Windows or on Linux  (gfortran 5.5.0 and 6.4.0), I get something strange:

```
START
Hello
Hola
Hello
1.00000000
Hey!
Hello
2.00000000
Ho!
you
OK
3.00000000

@R
4.00000000

ÇR@
END
```

And things are getting worse when I use this method in my big program with a segmentation fault.

So, is there a way to avoid these problems? Is it a bug of gfortran? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is at fault here.

Consider the section

```
proc =>procD
call proc(CA, 3.0)
```

which I'll first consider as

```
call procD(CA,3.0)
```

The subroutine `procD` has first dummy argument declared as `type(typeD)`.  This is a nonpolymorphic entity, of dynamic and declared type `typeD`.  The actual argument `CA` of the main program is a polymorphic entity of dynamic type `typeD` but declared type `typeA`.

In a procedure reference, it is necessary for each dummy argument to be type compatible with the actual argument with which it is associated.  This is not the case here: a nonpolymorphic object is type compatible only with entities of the same declared type as itself.  It is not type compatible with a polymorphic entity which while of the same dynamic type is not of the same declared type.

In the working version

```
call procD(Td, 2.0)
```

the actual argument `Td` is of declared type `typeD` and is therefore type compatible.

Using a procedure pointer with implicit interface here makes it harder for the compiler to detect this error in your program (which it isn't required to do).

Comment: If I understand well, I should change `type(typeD)` in the subroutine `procD` into `class(typeD)`, to get a polymorphic argument. But I do so, the procedure pointer `proc` will ask an interface. And the interface will require to use `class(TypeA)` as the parent polymorphic argument and therefore I will not be able to call object embedded in `TypeC` or `TypeD` according to the situation, since these objects are part of `TypeA`. So there is no real solution to do what I want ?

Comment: That complication is why I avoided a "and this is what you should do instead..." statement to conclude.  Exactly the best way to do things will depend on your full design goals, but reconsidering avoiding generics would be my first recommendation.  You may also have options around wrappers with an intermediate nonpolymorphic thing.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Except that I am not sure to fully understand your point on "wrappers with an intermediate nonpolymorphic thing". Can you precise a bit your idea ?

Comment: On reflection (thanks for asking!), the wrapper idea I partly formed is terrible.  There may be another idea along the same lines but I'd better not explain it until I think properly about it.  [Or someone else may.]

Comment: Though not sure, how about using "select type" in procC() and procD(), after changing the declaration of the dummy "fd" to class(TypeA) and changing proc as "procedure(procC), pointer :: proc"?

Comment: @roygvib, that is a viable way.  One I don't particularly like but it may indeed just come to that.  After generics/dynamic dispatch!

Comment: @roygvib this kind of `select type` solution would be faster than a generic procedure ?

Comment: @R.N Actually, I'm still not clear about the meaning of "generic procedure" here (a set of overloaded procedures via interface block?), but I guess the overhead is rather marginal (though it depends on compilers...). Another point is that, in my understanding, the use of "select type" is sometimes considered not very good approach (and implies design issues). So I'm not very sure whether it is a good direction or not... (particularly because I haven't understood the goal of the Question very well, sorry..)

Comment: I solved my problem with the third option. We listed 3 different options. 1: use a generic procedure: I couldn't make it works properly. 2: use a select type inside the procedures. 3: remove the extended type and add allocatable equivalent type in the parent type.